# Save XDocument with indentation and xml:space="preserve"

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I want to pretty print an [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) but leaving white space inside `xml:space="preserve"` elements untouched.

This snippet:

```
new XDocument(
    new XElement("a",
        new XElement("b",
            new XElement("c"))))
    .Save(Console.Out);
```

Results in the following indented output (which is just want I want):

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c />
  </b>
</a>
```

However, let's say that I need to preserve white space inside the `<b>` element:

```
new XDocument(
    new XElement("a",
        new XElement("b",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "space", "preserve"),
            new XElement("c"))))
    .Save(Console.Out);
```

In this case I get the following output:

```
<a>
  <b xml:space="preserve">
    <c />
  </b>
</a>
```

This is not good, since indentation was added *inside* the `xml:space="preserve"` scope. The expected output in this case would be:

```
<a>
  <b xml:space="preserve"><c /></b>
</a>
```

I'm surprised that [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't support this by default.

Is it possible to get a pretty printed (indented) output from an [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) **and keeping white space inside `xml:space="preserve"` as-is**?

I understand that one option is to write my own [XmlWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation that takes care of this, but I would rather use something from the framework (if available).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in `XmlWriter`, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7007533/5311735) self-answered question. The bug is: `XmlWriter` will respect `space:preserve` tag *unless* there are *no whitespace* inside tag marked with this attribute. If there are no whitespace - it can (for some reason) add some. Because internally `XDocument` also uses `XmlWriter` - it shows the same behavior. And indeed if you add 0-length whitespace by hand, like this:

```
new XDocument(
    new XElement("a",
        new XElement("b",
           new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "space", "preserve"),
              new XText(""),
              new XElement("c"))))
.Save(Console.Out);
```

it will respect whitespace preserve tag and produce expected output.